# Telerik MVC Grid - HiddenIndexerInputForModel in ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

MVC3 and using the Telerik Grid.

I'm using Phil Haacks **[Hidden Indexer Input For Model](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)** to bring form values back. Only problem is that when using Ajax as the databinder any Templates used need to have a corresponding ClientTemplate.  This is where I'm having a problem.  How do I insert this, and the iterator into the ClientTemplate, which is expecting a string?

This is what I've tried to no avail ... when I run the page I get an error saying 'Iter' is not defined.

```
<% int Iter = 0; %>
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.TransferStudents)
       .Name("TransferStudents")
        .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Name)
                        .Width(250);
                    columns.Template(o =>{%> 

                        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.TransferStudents[Iter].StudentId)%>
                        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.TransferStudents[Iter].Transfer)%>
                        <%})
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='hidden' id='StudentId' value='<#= StudentId #>' /><input type='checkbox' name='Transfer' <#= Transfer?  \"checked='checked'\" :\"\" #> />")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: center;" })
                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: center;" })
                        .HeaderTemplate("Check All <input type='checkbox' id='chkAll' />")
                        .Width(105);
                    columns.Template(o =>{ %><% Iter = Iter + 1; %><%})
                        .ClientTemplate("<# Iter = Iter + 1; #>")
                        .Hidden();
                    columns.Template(o =>{ %><%: Html.HiddenIndexerInputForModel()%><% })
                        .ClientTemplate("<#= Html.HiddenIndexerInputForModel() #>")
                        .Hidden();
                })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Server).Select("_Transfer", "Administration"))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.Style(pagerStyles).PageSize(2, new[] { 5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 200 }).Position(GridPagerPosition.Top).Total((int)ViewData["total"]))
        .Sortable()
        .NoRecordsTemplate("<p class='instructions'>No Records Available</p>")
        .Render();
        %>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClientTemplate expects a string which will be translated to JavaScript and executed in the browser (client-side). Any server code such as Html.HiddenIndexerInputForModel() won't work - there is no JavaScript equivalent. You need to use plain html as you have done in the other column.

Comment: Found that this works
  
    columns.Template(o =>
                        { %><% Iter = Iter + 1; %><%})
                            .ClientTemplate("<# " + Iter++ + "; #>")
                            .Hidden();
                        columns.Template(o =>
                        { %><%: Html.HiddenIndexerInputForModel()%><% })
                             .ClientTemplate("<#= " + Html.HiddenIndexerInputForModel() + " #>")
                              .Hidden();